# Where does OutputDebugString go on Windows Universal Apps ? And how to capture messages from OutputDebugString?

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-10-universal, uap

Using [OutputDebugString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) is a common debugging technique for user mode debugging.

In *UWP/UAP/Metro* app developement on Windows 10, this debugging function is still available.

However, I would like to observe OutputDebugString messages **without attaching Visual Studio debugger (EDIT: or WinDbg)**.

Latest version of [DbgViewer from SysInternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) is able to observe UWP debug output, but I can't find the source code for this tool.

Actually, [DebugViewPP from CobaltFusion](https://github.com/CobaltFusion/DebugViewPP) appears to work for win32 apps only.

As a workaround, I could simply use [LogginChannel.LogMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.platforminstaller.logging.logmessage?view=iis-dotnet) **but I'm currently more interested by how OutputDebugString API work under UWP**.

Comment: Use windbg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools  And have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/reading-and-filtering-debugging-messages

Comment: Thanks for your message, however, it doesn't help to know how ::OutputDebugString API is implemented under UWP. Also, WinDbg is too heavy for my purpose.

Comment: In the page you linked for `OutputDebugString`:  _"...Note that this function calls the DbgPrint function to display the string..."_ Then follow my second link to receiving / processing these messages.

Comment: A debugger receives the string when it calls WaitForDebugEventEx(), OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT notification.  SysInternals' hack is to patch the OS kernel to get this for any process, not just the one that a debugger attached.  Using this yourself is not very practical, you'll lose the ability to debug your program the normal way.

Comment: Is there a way to launch a UWP app from WinDbgX, the preview version ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans, the good old way https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/reiley/2011/07/29/a-debugging-approach-to-outputdebugstring/ doesn't seem to be relevant for UWP app.

Answer (score -2):

OutputDebugString function exists in Kernel32.dll file, if you want to use it in UWP, you can import the dll file by DllImport.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern void OutputDebugString(string message);
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OutputDebugString("~~~OutputDebugString");
}
```